# Why IOException does not cover FileNotFoundException?

Tags: java, serialization

I try to deserialize a file and get FileNotFoundException. The `.cycles` file does not exist when the program is launched.

```
Cycles сl;
try {
    сl = Cycles.deserialize();
    logger.info("The Cycles object was successfully deserialized");
} catch (IOException e2) {
    logger.info("The Cycles object was not detected");
    ...
```

None of the above logs were output.

```
public static Cycles deserialize() throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fileIn = null;
        ObjectInputStream in = null;
        try {
            fileIn = new FileInputStream(
                    System.getProperty("user.home") + System.getProperty("file.separator") + ".cycles");
            in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            return (Cycles) in.readObject();
        } catch (IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
        }
    }
```

Doesn't IOException override FileNotFoundException? So I expected to get null from this method. But instead the program crashes.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\activeUser\.cycles (The specified file cannot be found)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at main.Cycles.deserialize(Cycles.java:56)
        at main.FirefoxHeadlessServer.main(FirefoxHeadlessServer.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at main.Cycles.deserialize(Cycles.java:67)
        at main.FirefoxHeadlessServer.main(FirefoxHeadlessServer.java:141)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: “Doesn’t IOException override FileNotFoundException”: no. It’s the other way around. But you *did* get null from the method, hence the second exception. Look again. The real problem is that you’re trying to catch the same exception twice. Remove the try/catches in `deserialize()` and let it throw.

Comment: The FileNotFoundException stack trace comes from `i.printStackTrace()`, meaning it was caught by the `catch (IOException i)` bit in `deserialize()`. The NullPointerException is a separate exception thrown by `in.close()` due to `in` not being initialized because the FileNotFoundException was thrown. Use a try-with-resources statement to handle closing the streams.

Comment: Related: it's considered by many to be bad practice to use exceptions to handle **un**exceptional conditions. Check for the existence of the file instead. Always use try-with-resources as has been suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get a `NullPointerException` because if the file is not found then `in` will be null and calling `in.close();` (in the `finally` block) throws a `NullPointerException`.

This is why we have "try with resources" since Java 1.7:

```
public static Cycles deserialize() {
    try (FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(
            System.getProperty("user.home") + System.getProperty("file.separator") + ".cycles");
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn)){
        return (Cycles) in.readObject();
    } catch (IOException i) {
        i.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd be inclined to do something like the following. I don't know if you intend the file to be Unix-style hidden - if so, it appears to be lacking an extension [or a name, depending on which way around you interpret it ;) ]. Serialization files, often use .ser so:

```
    public static Cycles deserialize() {
        Cycles result = null;
        Path p = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "cycles.ser");
        if (Files.exists(p)) {
            try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(Files.newInputStream(p))) {
                result = (Cycles) in.readObject();
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```